# Ubuntu fails to select correct display output on startup + xserver crash

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, video

Here's a fun foray into some issues I've been having installing + running Ubuntu 15.04...

On my (desktop) machine, I have video out from both my motherboard (DVI + VGA) and also video card (Geforce GTX 960, DisplayPort + HDMI). I (normally) do not use my motherboard's video out; everything should be coming from the video card.
I have Windows 7 installed on one hard drive (SSD); I want to install Ubuntu 15.04 on a separate harddrive (SSD) using a USB bootloader with Ubuntu 15.04.

When I boot into Ubuntu 15.04 using the USB bootloader, Ubuntu only looks for video output on the motherboard, rather than the video card. This is annoying for a couple reasons:

1. My monitors don't even have DVI or VGA output (had to find a HDMI -> DVI cable),
2. There's otherwise no indication that Ubuntu isn't using my video card's output (and so figuring out this is what was going on was a pain -- although I guessed as the Ubuntu startup sound still did play.

Is there any reason why Ubuntu can't / doesn't detect that it could + should be using my video card for outputting display? It seems like Ubuntu should be able to provide, or use, some 'generic' video card drivers that are enough to ensure video output from the card works.

Okay, on to the next issue -- after that whole mess, I'm able to get Ubuntu 15.04 installed. However, when I attempt to boot into Ubuntu, the display server (`xserver`) fails to initialize. The logs seem to indicate that `xserver` is crashing on a null pointer exception. (Sorry, I don't have the crash logs -- it's harder to copy those over when all I have is a terminal, and no other hard-drives on my system seem visible in the mount. I am however able to access a terminal with e.g. `Ctrl + Alt + F1`.).

I do not see this with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and so have rolled back there for now, but any ideas on why, exactly, this might be happening?

EDIT: Although I was able to resolve this by updating the kernel, I thought I'd post the startup logs + crash dump in any case (with timing stripped):

```
X.Org X Server 1.17.1
Release Date: 2015-02-10
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-79-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux kevin-Z68X-UD3H-B3 3.16.0-38-generic #52-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 7 10:51:21 UTC 2015 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-38-generic root=UUID=7cb7429e-756d-4b07-b226-ef75f21de60c ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
Build Date: 03 June 2015  04:44:17AM
xorg-server 2:1.17.1-0ubuntu4 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.32.6
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
ure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
 command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
ing, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.1.log", Time: Mon Jun  8 17:53:37 2015
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
(==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
(**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
(**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
(==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
efault monitor configuration.
(==) Automatically adding devices
(==) Automatically enabling devices
(==) Automatically adding GPU devices
(WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
    Entry deleted from font path.
(WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
    Entry deleted from font path.
(WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
    Entry deleted from font path.
(WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
    Entry deleted from font path.
(WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
    Entry deleted from font path.
(==) FontPath set to:
e/fonts/X11/misc,
e/fonts/X11/Type1,

(==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
(II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
ices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
(II) Loader magic: 0x7fa8f8970d80
(II) Module ABI versions:
    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
    X.Org Video Driver: 19.0
    X.Org XInput driver : 21.0
    X.Org Server Extension : 9.0
(II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
(--) PCI: (0:0:2:0) 8086:0162:1458:d000 rev 9, Mem @ 0xfb400000/4194304, 0xc0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000ff00/64
(--) PCI:*(0:1:0:0) 10de:1401:3842:3966 rev 161, Mem @ 0xf9000000/16777216, 0xd0000000/268435456, 0xee000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000cf00/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
(II) LoadModule: "glx"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
(II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 1.0.0
    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 9.0
(==) AIGLX enabled
(==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 0
(==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 1
(==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 2
(==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 3
(==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 4
(==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 5
(==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
(II) LoadModule: "intel"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
(EE) Failed to load /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so: undefined symbol: xorgMir
(II) UnloadModule: "intel"
(II) Unloading intel
(EE) Failed to load module "intel" (loader failed, 7)
(II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so
(II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
(II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
(EE) Failed to load /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so: undefined symbol: xorgMir
(II) UnloadModule: "nouveau"
(II) Unloading nouveau
(EE) Failed to load module "nouveau" (loader failed, 7)
(II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
(II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 1.17.1
    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
(II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
(II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 0.4.4
    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
(II) LoadModule: "vesa"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
(II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 2.3.3
    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
(==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 0
(==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 1
(==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 2
(==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 3
(==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 4
(==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 5
(==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
(II) LoadModule: "intel"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
(EE) Failed to load /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so: undefined symbol: xorgMir
(II) UnloadModule: "intel"
(II) Unloading intel
(EE) Failed to load module "intel" (loader failed, 7)
(II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so
(II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
(II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
(II) Unloading nvidia
(II) Failed to load module "nvidia" (already loaded, 7)
(II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
(EE) Failed to load /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so: undefined symbol: xorgMir
(II) UnloadModule: "nouveau"
(II) Unloading nouveau
(EE) Failed to load module "nouveau" (loader failed, 7)
(II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
(II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 1.17.1
    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
(II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
(II) Unloading modesetting
(II) Failed to load module "modesetting" (already loaded, 7)
(II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
(II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 0.4.4
    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
(II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
(II) Unloading fbdev
(II) Failed to load module "fbdev" (already loaded, 7)
(II) LoadModule: "vesa"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
(II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 2.3.3
    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
(II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
(II) Unloading vesa
(II) Failed to load module "vesa" (already loaded, 7)
(II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  346.72  Tue May  5 16:47:26 PDT 2015
(II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
(II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
(II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
(II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
(++) using VT number 7

(II) Loading sub module "fb"
(II) LoadModule: "fb"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
(II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 1.0.0
    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
(II) Loading sub module "wfb"
(II) LoadModule: "wfb"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
(II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 1.0.0
    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
(II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
(II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
(II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
(EE) NVIDIA: Failed to initialize the NVIDIA kernel module. Please see the
(EE) NVIDIA:     system's kernel log for additional error messages and
(EE) NVIDIA:     consult the NVIDIA README for details.
(EE) NVIDIA: Failed to initialize the NVIDIA kernel module. Please see the
(EE) NVIDIA:     system's kernel log for additional error messages and
(EE) NVIDIA:     consult the NVIDIA README for details.
(II) modeset(G0): using drv /dev/dri/card0
(WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
(II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
(II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
(II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 0.0.2
    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
(**) FBDEV(1): claimed PCI slot 1@0:0:0
(II) FBDEV(1): using default device
(WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
(EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
(II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
(II) FBDEV(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
(==) FBDEV(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
(==) FBDEV(0): RGB weight 888
(==) FBDEV(0): Default visual is TrueColor
(==) FBDEV(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
(II) FBDEV(0): hardware: inteldrmfb (video memory: 10240kB)
(II) FBDEV(0): checking modes against framebuffer device...
(II) FBDEV(0): checking modes against monitor...
(--) FBDEV(0): Virtual size is 2048x1280 (pitch 2048)
(**) FBDEV(0):  Built-in mode "current"
(==) FBDEV(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
(II) Loading sub module "fb"
(II) LoadModule: "fb"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
(II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 1.0.0
    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
(**) FBDEV(0): using shadow framebuffer
(II) Loading sub module "shadow"
(II) LoadModule: "shadow"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libshadow.so
(II) Module shadow: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 1.1.0
    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
(==) modeset(G0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
(==) modeset(G0): RGB weight 888
(==) modeset(G0): Default visual is TrueColor
(II) Loading sub module "glamoregl"
(II) LoadModule: "glamoregl"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so
(II) Module glamoregl: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 1.0.0
    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
(II) glamor: OpenGL accelerated X.org driver based.
couldn't get display device
(EE) modeset(G0): glamor initialization failed
(II) modeset(G0): ShadowFB: preferred YES, enabled YES
(II) modeset(G0): Output VGA-1-0 has no monitor section
(II) modeset(G0): Output HDMI-1-0 has no monitor section
(II) modeset(G0): Output DisplayPort-1-0 has no monitor section
(II) modeset(G0): Output HDMI-1-1 has no monitor section
(II) modeset(G0): Output HDMI-1-2 has no monitor section
(II) modeset(G0): Output DisplayPort-1-1 has no monitor section
(II) modeset(G0): Output DisplayPort-1-2 has no monitor section
(II) modeset(G0): EDID for output VGA-1-0
(II) modeset(G0): EDID for output HDMI-1-0
(II) modeset(G0): Manufacturer: DEL  Model: a0c0  Serial#: 809848396
(II) modeset(G0): Year: 2014  Week: 50
(II) modeset(G0): EDID Version: 1.3
(II) modeset(G0): Digital Display Input
(II) modeset(G0): Max Image Size [cm]: horiz.: 53  vert.: 30
(II) modeset(G0): Gamma: 2.20
(II) modeset(G0): DPMS capabilities: StandBy Suspend Off
(II) modeset(G0): Supported color encodings: RGB 4:4:4 YCrCb 4:4:4 
(II) modeset(G0): First detailed timing is preferred mode
(II) modeset(G0): redX: 0.659 redY: 0.334   greenX: 0.301 greenY: 0.639
(II) modeset(G0): blueX: 0.149 blueY: 0.043   whiteX: 0.313 whiteY: 0.329
(II) modeset(G0): Supported established timings:
(II) modeset(G0): 720x400@70Hz
(II) modeset(G0): 640x480@60Hz
(II) modeset(G0): 640x480@75Hz
(II) modeset(G0): 800x600@60Hz
(II) modeset(G0): 800x600@75Hz
(II) modeset(G0): 1024x768@60Hz
(II) modeset(G0): 1024x768@75Hz
(II) modeset(G0): 1280x1024@75Hz
(II) modeset(G0): Manufacturer's mask: 0
(II) modeset(G0): Supported standard timings:
(II) modeset(G0): #0: hsize: 1152  vsize 864  refresh: 75  vid: 20337
(II) modeset(G0): #1: hsize: 1280  vsize 1024  refresh: 60  vid: 32897
(II) modeset(G0): #2: hsize: 1600  vsize 900  refresh: 60  vid: 49321
(II) modeset(G0): #3: hsize: 1600  vsize 1200  refresh: 60  vid: 16553
(II) modeset(G0): #4: hsize: 1920  vsize 1080  refresh: 60  vid: 49361
(II) modeset(G0): #5: hsize: 2048  vsize 1280  refresh: 60  vid: 225
(II) modeset(G0): Supported detailed timing:
(II) modeset(G0): clock: 262.8 MHz   Image Size:  527 x 296 mm
(II) modeset(G0): h_active: 3840  h_sync: 3888  h_sync_end 3920 h_blank_end 4000 h_border: 0
(II) modeset(G0): v_active: 2160  v_sync: 2163  v_sync_end 2168 v_blanking: 2191 v_border: 0
(II) modeset(G0): Serial No: Y9PCD4C80ENL
(II) modeset(G0): Monitor name: DELL P2415Q
(II) modeset(G0): Ranges: V min: 29 V max: 76 Hz, H min: 30 H max: 140 kHz, PixClock max 305 MHz
(II) modeset(G0): Supported detailed timing:
(II) modeset(G0): clock: 148.5 MHz   Image Size:  527 x 296 mm
(II) modeset(G0): h_active: 1920  h_sync: 2008  h_sync_end 2052 h_blank_end 2200 h_border: 0
(II) modeset(G0): v_active: 1080  v_sync: 1082  v_sync_end 1087 v_blanking: 1125 v_border: 0
(II) modeset(G0): Supported detailed timing:
(II) modeset(G0): clock: 74.2 MHz   Image Size:  527 x 296 mm
(II) modeset(G0): h_active: 1920  h_sync: 2008  h_sync_end 2052 h_blank_end 2200 h_border: 0
(II) modeset(G0): v_active: 540  v_sync: 542  v_sync_end 547 v_blanking: 562 v_border: 0
(II) modeset(G0): Supported detailed timing:
(II) modeset(G0): clock: 297.0 MHz   Image Size:  527 x 296 mm
(II) modeset(G0): h_active: 3840  h_sync: 4016  h_sync_end 4104 h_blank_end 4400 h_border: 0
(II) modeset(G0): v_active: 2160  v_sync: 2168  v_sync_end 2178 v_blanking: 2250 v_border: 0
(II) modeset(G0): Supported detailed timing:
(II) modeset(G0): clock: 241.5 MHz   Image Size:  527 x 296 mm
(II) modeset(G0): h_active: 2560  h_sync: 2608  h_sync_end 2640 h_blank_end 2720 h_border: 0
(II) modeset(G0): v_active: 1440  v_sync: 1443  v_sync_end 1448 v_blanking: 1481 v_border: 0
(II) modeset(G0): Number of EDID sections to follow: 1
(II) modeset(G0): EDID (in hex):
(II) modeset(G0):   00ffffffffffff0010acc0a04c4e4530
(II) modeset(G0):   3218010380351e78eae245a8554da326
(II) modeset(G0):   0b5054a54b00714f8180a9c0a940d1c0
(II) modeset(G0):   e10001010101a36600a0f0701f803020
(II) modeset(G0):   35000f282100001a000000ff00593950
(II) modeset(G0):   434434433830454e4c0a000000fc0044
(II) modeset(G0):   454c4c205032343135510a20000000fd
(II) modeset(G0):   001d4c1e8c1e000a202020202020015a
(II) modeset(G0):   02032af15390050402071601141f1213
(II) modeset(G0):   2720212203061115230907076d030c00
(II) modeset(G0):   1000303c200060030201023a80187138
(II) modeset(G0):   2d40582c25000f282100001f011d8018
(II) modeset(G0):   711c1620582c25000f282100009e0474
(II) modeset(G0):   0030f2705a80b0588a000f282100001e
(II) modeset(G0):   565e00a0a0a02950302035000f282100
(II) modeset(G0):   001a00000000000000000000000000f9
(--) modeset(G0): HDMI max TMDS frequency 300000KHz
(II) modeset(G0): Printing probed modes for output HDMI-1-0
(II) modeset(G0): Modeline "2048x1280"x60.0  221.28  2048 2192 2416 2784  1280 1281 1284 1325 -hsync +vsync (79.5 kHz)
(II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1920x1080"x60.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1082 1087 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
(II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1920x1080"x60.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
(II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1920x1080"x50.0  148.50  1920 2448 2492 2640  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (56.2 kHz e)
(II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1920x1080"x59.9  148.35  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.4 kHz e)
(II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1920x1080i"x60.0   74.25  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1094 1125 interlace +hsync +vsync (33.8 kHz e)
(II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1920x1080i"x50.0   74.25  1920 2448 2492 2640  1080 1084 1094 1125 interlace +hsync +vsync (28.1 kHz e)
(II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1920x1080"x30.0   74.25  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (33.8 kHz e)
(II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1920x1080"x25.0   74.25  1920 2448 2492 2640  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (28.1 kHz e)
(II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1920x1080"x24.0   74.25  1920 2558 2602 2750  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (27.0 kHz e)
(II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1920x1080i"x59.9   74.18  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1094 1125 interlace +hsync +vsync (33.7 kHz e)
(II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1920x1080"x30.0   74.18  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (33.7 kHz e)
(II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1920x1080"x24.0   74.18  1920 2558 2602 2750  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (27.0 kHz e)
(II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1920x1080i"x50.0   72.00  1920 1952 2120 2304  1080 1126 1136 1250 interlace +hsync -vsync (31.2 kHz e)
(II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1600x1200"x60.0  162.00  1600 1664 1856 2160  1200 1201 1204 1250 +hsync +vsync (75.0 kHz e)
(II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1600x900"x60.0  118.96  1600 1696 1864 2128  900 901 904 932 -hsync +vsync (55.9 kHz)
(II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1280x1024"x75.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
(II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1280x1024"x60.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
(II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1152x864"x75.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
(II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1280x720"x60.0   74.25  1280 1390 1430 1650  720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync (45.0 kHz e)
(II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1280x720"x50.0   74.25  1280 1720 1760 1980  720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync (37.5 kHz e)
(II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1280x720"x59.9   74.18  1280 1390 1430 1650  720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync (45.0 kHz e)
(II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1440x576i"x50.0   27.00  1440 1464 1590 1728  576 580 586 625 interlace -hsync -vsync (15.6 kHz e)
(II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1024x768"x75.1   78.80  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.1 kHz e)
(II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1024x768"x60.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
(II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1440x480i"x60.0   27.03  1440 1478 1602 1716  480 488 494 525 interlace -hsync -vsync (15.8 kHz e)
(II) modeset(G0): Modeline "1440x480i"x59.9   27.00  1440 1478 1602 1716  480 488 494 525 interlace -hsync -vsync (15.7 kHz e)
(II) modeset(G0): Modeline "800x600"x75.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
(II) modeset(G0): Modeline "800x600"x60.3   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
(II) modeset(G0): Modeline "720x576"x50.0   27.00  720 732 796 864  576 581 586 625 -hsync -vsync (31.2 kHz e)
(II) modeset(G0): Modeline "720x480"x60.0   27.03  720 736 798 858  480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
(II) modeset(G0): Modeline "720x480"x59.9   27.00  720 736 798 858  480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
(II) modeset(G0): Modeline "640x480"x75.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
(II) modeset(G0): Modeline "640x480"x60.0   25.20  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
(II) modeset(G0): Modeline "640x480"x59.9   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
(II) modeset(G0): Modeline "720x400"x70.1   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
(II) modeset(G0): EDID for output DisplayPort-1-0
(II) modeset(G0): EDID for output HDMI-1-1
(II) modeset(G0): EDID for output HDMI-1-2
(II) modeset(G0): EDID for output DisplayPort-1-1
(II) modeset(G0): EDID for output DisplayPort-1-2
(II) modeset(G0): Using default gamma of (1.0, 1.0, 1.0) unless otherwise stated.
(==) modeset(G0): DPI set to (96, 96)
(II) Loading sub module "fb"
(II) LoadModule: "fb"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
(II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 1.0.0
    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
(II) Loading sub module "shadow"
(II) LoadModule: "shadow"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libshadow.so
(II) Module shadow: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 1.1.0
    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
(II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
(II) Unloading vesa
(==) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
(==) modeset(G0): Backing store enabled
(==) modeset(G0): Silken mouse enabled
(II) modeset(G0): RandR 1.2 enabled, ignore the following RandR disabled message.
(==) modeset(G0): DPMS enabled
(==) FBDEV(0): Backing store enabled
(EE) FBDEV(0): FBIOPUTCMAP: Device or resource busy
(EE) < ... >
(EE) < ... above message repeats many times ... >
(EE) < ... >
(==) FBDEV(0): DPMS enabled
(--) RandR disabled
(II) SELinux: Disabled on system
(II) AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI2 capable
(EE) AIGLX: reverting to software rendering
(EE) AIGLX error: dlopen of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so: undefined symbol: _glapi_tls_Dispatch)
(EE) GLX: could not load software renderer
(II) GLX: no usable GL providers found for screen 0
(II) modeset(G0): Damage tracking initialized
(EE) 
(EE) Backtrace:
(EE) 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x56) [0x7fa8f86e9346]
(EE) 1: /usr/bin/X (0x7fa8f8536000+0x1b74a9) [0x7fa8f86ed4a9]
(EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x7fa8f61fb000+0x352f0) [0x7fa8f62302f0]
(EE) 3: /usr/bin/X (RRSetChanged+0x50) [0x7fa8f864d4a0]
(EE) 4: /usr/bin/X (RRScreenSetSizeRange+0x54) [0x7fa8f86519d4]
(EE) 5: /usr/bin/X (xf86RandR12CreateScreenResources+0x2a5) [0x7fa8f860e965]
(EE) 6: /usr/bin/X (0x7fa8f8536000+0xcbc00) [0x7fa8f8601c00]
(EE) 7: /usr/bin/X (0x7fa8f8536000+0x5c094) [0x7fa8f8592094]
(EE) 8: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf0) [0x7fa8f621ba40]
(EE) 9: /usr/bin/X (_start+0x29) [0x7fa8f857c5b9]
(EE) 
(EE) Segmentation fault at address 0xa0
(EE) 
error:
(EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
(EE) 
(EE) 
t the The X.Org Foundation support 
//wiki.x.org

(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.1.log" for additional information.
(EE) 
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I don't have a resolution for the first 'video card' issue (I'm going to just imagine that this is why Linus gave Nvidia the finger), the second was resolved by updating the kernel, with

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic
```